# Umm, accidentally hid Sublime Text 3's Menu and can't get it back

Tags: sublimetext3

Okay, uh, this is pretty stupid. I accidentally pressed "Hide Menu" in Sublime Text 3's "View" dropdown menu, and now the top bar is hidden from me, hehe. You know the one? With the "File" and "Edit" dropdown menus. Yeah, well, now I can't get it back. What do I do?

This has got to be one of the stupidest questions asked on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press alt and it should pop up.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much kind StackOverflow User!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this options:

- Press "Alt" key.
- Press Ctrl+Shift+P and type "menu"